# PyQt5 FileDialog: Show network folders

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qfiledialog

My system is as follows: python 3.6.0 with PyQt 5.8.1 installed in an anaconda environment on ubuntu 16.10.

I want to show/select network folders (connected via samba) with the PyQt5 FileDialog, but am unable to do so.
In PyQt4 (another environment) it works.

relevant code:
        from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
        fileDialog=QtWidgets.QFileDialog()
        workDirectory = str(fileDialog.getExistingDirectory(caption= "Set Work Directory", directory=defaultWorkDirectory))
        fileDialog.deleteLater()

The PyQt5 documentation just leads to the C++ one and there is this about network/local files: "Note: The non-native QFileDialog supports only local files." and "When possible, this static function will use the native file dialog and not a QFileDialog. On platforms which don't support selecting remote files, Qt will allow to select only local files."
I thought, ubuntu supports this (just like in PyQt4).

Is there a way to do this or do i have to settle with PyQt4?

Thanks,
Topsrek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the gtk3 file dialog hides non-local files by default. (this has to be explicitly enabled in the Qt gtk3 platform implementation, [bugreport](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59705))

Qt4 doesn’t have gtk3 support so you get a gtk2 file dialog which doesn’t do this.

I didn’t find a way to get Qt5 to use the gtk2 dialog and as you found out yourself the non-native dialog doesn’t support network locations either.

As a workaround you can navigate to already mounted locations in `/run/user/(your username)/gvfs/*`.
As ugly as this may seem, I suggest using this instead of going back to PyQt4.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wants to modify this behavior in Qt5, here is one solution. In `qtbase/src/plugins/platformthemes/gtk3/qgtk3dialoghelpers.cpp`, change the parameter of `gtk_file_chooser_set_local_only`:

```cpp
void QGtk3FileDialogHelper::applyOptions()
{
    GtkDialog *gtkDialog = d->gtkDialog();
    const QSharedPointer<QFileDialogOptions> &opts = options();

    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(gtkDialog), qUtf8Printable(opts->windowTitle()));
    //gtk_file_chooser_set_local_only(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(gtkDialog), true);
    gtk_file_chooser_set_local_only(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(gtkDialog), false);
    //...
}
```

Now the GTK 3 file dialog can show the mounted shares. See [gtk-file-chooser-set-local-only](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-set-local-only).